# Should you use `npm-link` in production

Tags: reactjs, npm, production-environment, npm-link

So let's say I've created a package with certain modules (or React components) and I have multiple projects that could use the same modules. I use `npm link` to do this and it works fine in development. But is it advisable to do the same in production? Can I even do this in production or is `npm link` to be used only for development/debugging purposes. Are there any issues that could come from setting this up in prod?

I'm only now learning about npm link so any suggestion or link to relevant documents would be appreciated.